# How to collect data into a single List with a while loop?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In my Play Scala app I am using a SOAP api library by way of a jar file.  In this interface there is no way to fetch all domain items with on call; the docs suggest the developer to use a fetchDeltaSince with pagination parameters.

If I am to fetch any domain created between startTime and endTime I would have to utilize a method like this:

```
Account::fetchDeltaSince(startTime : Calendar, page : Int, pageSize : Int, endTime : Calendar) : Array[Account]
```

pageSize max that is allowed is 100 and there are about 30K+ accounts.  I will have to get this data using some sort of while loop that monitors the number of items returned and incrementing page parameter (maybe?).  I would like for the result to be all in one `Array[Account]` datatype.

What is the best way to do this in Scala and is there a way to do it asynchronously?

Comment: A few questions: can you be sure that you won't get so many requests that building this big array won't cause memory issues? If you aren't then are you forced do use `while, or you just need any looping?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok 1) I am not sure that it won't cause memory issues.  If it does, I can extract the attributes from SOAP that I care about and convert the SOAP Account contract into a much leaner Account Contract for working with in memory. 2) I don't THINK it has to be a while loop.  I would prefer if it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your fetching has more or less this signature:

```
def fetchDeltaSince(startTime: Calendar, page: Int, pageSize: Int, endTime: Calendar): Array[Account]
```

you could have an async version of it that is e.g. `Future`:

```
def fetchDeltaSinceAsync(startTime: Calendar, page: Int, pageSize: Int, endTime: Calendar): Future[Array[Account]]
```

and then you could combine it like e.g.

```
def fetchAll(startTime: Calendar,
             pageSize: Int,
             endTime: Calendar): Future[List[Account]] = {
  def fetchUntilAll(page: Int, listBuffer: ListBuffer[Account]): Future[List[Account]]
    fetchDeltaSinceAsync(startTime, page, pageSize, endTime).flatMap { newBatch =>
      if (newBatch.isEmpty) Future.successful(listBuffer.toList)
      else fetchUntilAll(page + 1, listBuffer ++= newBatch)
    }
  fetchUntilAll(0, new ListBuffer[Account]())
}
```

I used `ListBuffer` it avoid reallocating `List` again and again. In your code you would have to adjust e.g. stop condition (maybe it is not empty array but exception, or sth else?). You might also prefer to use something more functional e.g. replace `Future` with Monix's `Task` and `ListBuffer` with Cats' `Chain`.

Comment: Thanks you very much.  Something like this works great.  Also cheers for the functional hints.  There were a couple typos in there, but it's not hard to figure out what to do to fix ;)